# Why am I not able to migrate the question to codereview.stackexchange site using close voting

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration

Recently I saw [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305623/select-top-n-rows-from-datatable-c-sharp-windows-form-application) which is related to, do the specific problem in a better or any other way. The OP's code is working fine and he is asking for the another option. I think this type of question should be asked on CodeReview.Stackexchange. So I voted this to close and select the reason as *it belongs to another stackexchange site.* But where It only shows couple of site in which CodeReview.Stackexchange is not available.

So may I know why this option is not there?